# Эффект матрицы С/С++

Tags: c++, c

Как можно сделать такой эффект матрицы (как на фото) на с/с++?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `cat /dev/random`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например вот:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int Modulus(int iN, int iMod) {
    int iQ = (iN / iMod);
    return iN - (iQ * iMod);
}

char GetChar(int iGenerator, char cBase, int iRange) {
    return (cBase + Modulus(iGenerator, iRange));
}

int main() {
    //Устанавливаем цвет
    HANDLE  hConsole;
    hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 2);

    char caRow[80];
    int j = 7;
    int k = 2;
    int l = 5;
    int m = 1;
    while (true) {
        int i = 0;
        //Случайные символы
        while (i < 80) {
            if (caRow[i] != ' ') {
                caRow[i] = GetChar(j + i * i, 33, 30);
                if (((i * i + k) % 71) == 0) {
                    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 7);
                }
                else {
                    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 2);
                }
            }
            std::cout << caRow[i];
            ++i;
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, 2);
        }
        j = (j + 31);
        k = (k + 17);
        l = (l + 47);
        m = (m + 67);
        caRow[Modulus(j, 80)] = '-';
        caRow[Modulus(k, 80)] = ' ';
        caRow[Modulus(l, 80)] = '-';
        caRow[Modulus(m, 80)] = ' ';
        //Задержка
        Sleep(10);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Выглядит примерно так же, как на скриншоте.

Comment: А можно добавить еще комментарии в код что бы можно было разобраться в коде и если нужно будет поправить?

Comment: Ну если вкратце, то все `caRow`, `Modulus` переменные `j, k, l, m` и т.д. нужны просто для красивого рандома :)

Comment: Если писали код не сами, стоит указать ссылку на источник.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat у меня нет ссылки на источник к сожалению. Просто в папке с забытыми проектами валялся. Я думаю можно в гугле по запросу `"эффект матрицы c++"` найти.

Comment: Я понял спасибо